# Why I have addition '/' character when using BeautifulSoup.find_all function?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I tried to find image tags from a HTML page like this:

`<img src="../img/gifts/img1.jpg">`

`<img src="../img/gifts/img1.jpg">`

etc....

but when I use this code from Web Scraping 2 - author: Ryan Mitchell

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = urlopen('http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
images = bs.find_all('img',{'src':re.compile('\.\.\/img\/gifts/img.*\.jpg')})
```

the list of tags I received look like this:

```
[<img src="../img/gifts/img1.jpg"/>,
 <img src="../img/gifts/img2.jpg"/>,
 <img src="../img/gifts/img3.jpg"/>,
 <img src="../img/gifts/img4.jpg"/>,
 <img src="../img/gifts/img6.jpg"/>]
```

I saw that there is an additional '/' character at the end of each tag? Can someone explain this for me?
Thank so much

Comment: That is BeautifulSoup's representation of the node in it's parsed DOM. The source code itself is unimportant as soon as the HTML is parsed into a DOM. The trailing slash is optional in most HTML versions, except XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML the tags which don't have an end tag, are ended with `/>`. This is optional in most HTML versions, except XHTML where it is mandatory, and it is good practice. Beautifulsoup API automatically adds this to prettify the parsed DOM.